# Need clarification regarding custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on the custom post-types. Once i added the post types i can able to post the data. Custom post types are done by using the CMS-PRESS. After i posted the particular custom post - type post i'm not able to see the post in the wordpress post list in front-end. And same like it's not coming under the buddypress too. How i can make this affect in all the places same like the normal post ?? and is it possible to make a theme based on the post type?? Could any one can help me on this??

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have misunderstood the purpose of custom post types.

It's probably more helpful to think of them as custom 'entities' rather than custom 'posts'. Examples of custom entities could be 'Cars', 'Courses', 'Locations' or almost anything else you could put on a web site.

Once you start thinking that way, you see how WordPress needs some help knowing how to display those entities. Some custom entities may be added regularly; others may remain unchanged for months or years. Some may be small in number; other may need to be displayed in a complex hierarchy or through a search.

That's why they are kept separate from your blog, in the same way that pages are.

However, if custom 'posts' are the right thing for you to use, there are some great resources on the wordpress site for developing or modifying your theme to design them in. There is also a neat shortcut, in the 'Get Posts' plugin. You can find it in the normal add-ons directory.

Hope this sets you in the right direction :-)

Comment: yes you are right! i misunderstood the purpose of custom posts but now i'm clear. But could you explain me where i can see the added custom posts in my blog?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment, Mayilarun:

OK, there are two ways in which you can see your custom posts: As a list of entries, and individually.

To see an individual entry, you essentially link to it through the permalink structure. For example, you might create a link to mysite.com/locations/lakeside.

However this is a bit static. So if you want to see a list of entries, in the same way as in a blog, you need to code the Wordpress get_posts() function into your theme. This is well documented on the Wordpress site, provided you have the programming skills to go with it!

If you're not too keen on writing your own theme, you can instead use the plugin 'Get Posts' which allows you to embed a shortcode in the content of any page and return a list of entries. It is highly customisable and there are a few ready-to-go examples on the plugin author's web site. Just make sure you add the post_type entry into the shortcode. On a site I just created it started like this:

[get_posts post_type="Products" ...

Good luck!